# Open Blob fields using Openrowset in SQLSERVER 2008 R2

Tags: file, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

I need help to read a fileobject from SQLServer2008 R2 using the Openrowset, i can write a File to a Blob column like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(FileName, FileType, Document) 
   SELECT 'Text1.txt' AS FileName, 
      '.txt' AS FileType, 
      * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;
```

but how do i read it back and write it to the disk?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)** utility in conjunction with the queryout argument to save a blob to disk.

```
bcp "select datei 
     from   Adventureworks.Person.Address 
     WHERE  addressid=1 " 
queryout "c:\TestOut.doc" -T -n -Slocalhost
```

There are some good examples at the [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) reference page, as well as plenty of command line options.